# Multiple versions of an npm package causes to fail react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I am using an old version of react-native-webview for iOS and the latest version for Android in a react-native app. App runs in iOS successfully, however Android gives an error that says "**Native module RNCWebView tried to override RNCWebViewModule...**"
I checked getPackages() in MainApplication.java but there is **no duplicate creation or multiple imports** for react-native-webview or react-native-webview-latest.

Also, I added

```
@Override    
public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
  return true;    
}
```

to RNCWebViewModule.java file under node_modules/react-native-webview-latest/... but it does not work.

Relevant lines from package.json file:

```
"react-native-webview": "6.11.1",
"react-native-webview-latest": "npm:react-native-webview@11.6.2",
```

How can eliminate this error and get a successful Android run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it was adding two webview packages to generated PackageList.java file.

My dependencies in package.json:

```
 "react-native-webview-old": "npm:react-native-webview@6.11.1",
 "react-native-webview-latest": "npm:react-native-webview@11.6.2"
```

At first, I added a script in package.json to remove android folder in the old version of rn webview after npm install like below:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "i": "npm i && rm -rf node_modules/react-native-webview-old/android"
  },
```

Now, I'm using **npm run i** to install dependencies.

I was trying to import WebViews like this:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview-old';
import { WebView as WebViewLatest } from 'react-native-webview-latest';
```

Then, I changed these lines to

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
let WebView;
if (Platform.OS === 'android') WebView = require('react-native-webview-latest').WebView;
else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') WebView = require('react-native-webview-old').WebView;
```

This fixed the problem.